# Feature with very few extreme values

Tags: machine-learning, data-transformation, feature-engineering

As a set of inputs into a machine learning model with ~10 million samples, I have a feature that exhibits a pretty extreme shape. Most of the values (98.5%) are 0, but those that aren't 0 tend to be very extreme, as high as on the order of 1e9. Despite the overwhelming number of 0s, the mean is 2.59e4 and the variance is 7.92e5.

If anything, should I apply some sort of transformation to this dataset? Maybe something like a log transformation? How should I think of something like this?

Comment: Sounds like a case where you may want to transform it into a binary (zero/non-zero) variable. This depends on the context of your problem though, of course.

Comment: scale is not a problem, and scaling is the easiest thing to do. anyway, what's the distribution of those non zero values?